# Table view same cellForRowAt usage for two different cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have table view (not table view controller). Table view's one cell is collection view and the others only text labels. Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var imageNames = [ImageNames]()
    var foodNames = [FoodNames]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageNames = [
            ImageNames(name: "images"),
            ImageNames(name: "unnamed"),
            ImageNames(name: "unnamed"),
            ImageNames(name: "images"),
            ImageNames(name: "images")
        ]

        foodNames = [
            FoodNames(title: "Hamburger hamburger big king big mac big chicken")
        ]

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 130
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  imageNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainFoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MainFoodTableViewCell

        cell?.mainFoodCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell?.mainFoodCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell?.mainFoodCollectionView.reloadData()
        cell?.mainFoodCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell!

    }


    //collection view cell size

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: ((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) + 16), height: 130)
    }

    //collection view cell data


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainFoodCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodCollectionViewCell
            let img = imageNames[indexPath.row]
           cell.mainFoodImage.image = UIImage(named: img.name)
        return cell
    }
}
```

How can I use in just below code in same cellForRowAt method.

```
    let food: FoodNames
    food = foodNames[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel!.text = food.title
```

I tried create other ViewController for text datas in other table view cells.

Conclusion I need one collection view in first cell of table view and the other cells should have only texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if you setup your table view with two sections. The first section would have one row for the cell with the collection view. The second section would have the rows for the elements of your `foodNames` array.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == 0 ? 1 : foodNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainFoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTableViewCell

        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.reloadData()
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    } else {
        // Use your actual id and cell class name
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoodNameCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodNameCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = foodNames[indexPath.row].title

        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 130 : 44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 100 : 44
}
```